# ¿Por qué no me carga el formulario tipo "POST"?

Tags: python, django

Explico un poco lo que quiero hacer: es para un sitio tipo blog; la idea es que un usuario logeado pueda publicar y editar páginas, por este motivo el modelo páginas tiene como “autor” al usuario. La idea es NO poner este campo a completar en el formulario al igual que la fecha de carga de manera tal que se carguen de forma automática.

Posteriormente necesito que este “autor” (el usuario logueado) también pueda subir una imagen a dicho post (página), por este motivo está el modelo `Imagenpost` para que la imagen esté vinculada a la página o posteo que se desee publicar y si se elimina dicho post la imagen también sea descartada.

Van a notar que lo que refiere a la imagen todavía no está representado en el código, quería ponerme con eso luego; primero quiero resolver el formulario de carga para dicho posteo.

Entonces necesito crear una vista basada en FUNCIONES (no tengo permitido usar vistas basadas en clases).

El problema está en que al ingresar en `publicar` no carga el formulario, carga solo el botón “publicar”.

Lo que noté en la view es que el formulario no está entrando con método `POST` y va directamente al último else.

```py
    class Pagina(models.Model):
        titulo=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    
        subtitulo=models.CharField(max_length=100)
        autor= models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        cuerpo=RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
        #cuerpo=models.TextField()
        fecha_posteo=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.titulo + " - " + str(self.autor)
    
    class Imagenpost(models.Model):
            imagen=models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="post")
            Pagina=models.ForeignKey(Pagina, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  #IMAGEN DEL POST RELACIONADAS A LAS PAGINAS
            fecha_imagen=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
    
    
    class nuevopostform(forms.Form):
        titulo=forms.CharField(label="Titulo", max_length=100)
        subtitulo=forms.CharField(label="Subtitulo", max_length=100)
        #imagen=forms.ImageField(label="Imagen")
        cuerpo=forms.CharField(label="Cuerpo", widget=CKEditorWidget())
    
        class Meta:
            model=Pagina
            fields=["titulo", "subtitulo", "autor", "cuerpo", "fecha_posteo"]
            help_texts = {k:"" for k in fields}
    
    
    @login_required
    def nuevopost(request):
        if request.method=="POST":
            formulario=nuevopostform(request.POST)
            if formulario.is_valid():
                informacion= formulario.cleaned_data
                titulo= informacion["titulo"]
                subtitulo= informacion["subtitulo"]
                #imagen= informacion["imagen"]
                cuerpo= informacion["cuerpo"]
                pagina= Pagina(titulo=titulo, subtitulo=subtitulo, cuerpo=cuerpo)
                pagina.save()
                posteos=Pagina.objects.all()
                return render(request, "pagina_detalle.html", {"posteos": posteos, "mensaje": "Blog guardado"})
            else:
                return render(request, "pagina_form_copia.html", {"mensaje": "Informacion no Valida"})
        else:
            formulario=nuevopostform()
            return render(request, "pagina_form_copia.html", {"formulario": formulario})
```

[image: Adjunto imagen, de la url donde deberia cargar el formulario y su cod html para el template de carga]

```xml
    <form action="{% url 'nuevopost' %}" method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
        <table>
            {{ form.as_table }}
        </table>
    <br/>
        <button class="btn btn-secondary">Publicar</a>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que en el context que estas enviando a tu template, lo envías como "**formulario**" pero en el template lo declaras como "**form**".
Para Django en en el método "**nuevopost**" no existe el form. Para que muestre tu formulario, en el template tendrías que poner el formulario.
Pongo el ejemplo:

```
<form action="{% url 'nuevopost' %}" method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        {{ formulario.as_table }}
    </table>
<br/>
    <button class="btn btn-secondary">Publicar</a>
</form>
```

Anexo un link de la documentación donde se habla más a detalle:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/#the-template

Espero haber sido de ayuda :)

Comment: Sos un genio de la vida y mereces todo lo bueno que te pase jajaja muchísimas gracias, el error estaba ahi

Comment: jajaj muchas gracias, si esto te sirvió, por favor marca la pregunta como resulta. Con eso me doy por bien servido. Gracias. Éxitos